# Postgresql query to find top voted tables within last 24 hours

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a complex PostgreSQL DB query that I am having difficulties constructing. I have two tables: a `post` table and a `votes` table. Below is what they look like:

The `post` table- I've only included the `id` because other columns aren't important to my question

```
 ---- 
| id |
 ----
```

The `votes` table- `vote_type` can either be `1` (upvote), `-1` (downvote), or `0` (neutral). The `post_id` is the id of the id of the post for the single vote.

```
 ---- --------- ----------- --------------------------------
| id | post_id | vote_type | timestamp                      |
 ---- --------- ----------- --------------------------------
| 1  | 4       | 1         |  2017-03-30 12:17:12.246765-07 |
```

Here's what I am trying to achieve: **Query top 10 posts with the most votes within the last 24 hours**

I've first constructed the following query:

```
SELECT postsTable.*, votesTable.votes
FROM posts AS postsTable
RIGHT JOIN (
  SELECT sum(vote_type) votes, post_id 
  FROM votes 
  WHERE (extract(day from age(now(), timestamp)) < 1) 
  GROUP BY post_id) 
  AS votesTable 
  ON (postsTable.id = votesTable.post_id)
ORDER BY votes DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 10;
```

Returns something like:

```
 ---- ---------------------- -------
| id | other_colums_between | votes |
 ---- ---------------------- -------
| 8  | ...                  | 1     |
```

It works slightly with the right posts BUT the votes column only shows the sum of votes within the last 24 hours NOT the total votes made since the post has been made (and that's what I want). The reason is because I am summing the votes only made within the last 24 hours and NOT all votes since the post has been created.

Say the `post` with `id` 8 has 10 votes. The query only returns 1 vote because only one upvote has been made within the last 24 hours.

Thus the query should return:

```
 ---- ---------------------- -------
| id | other_colums_between | votes |
 ---- ---------------------- -------
| 8  | ...                  | 10    |
```

So I know what I have to fix but I don't know how to do it. I've tried the query below but it's not what I want but I feel like I am getting closer. I haven't included the filtering for posts within the last 24 hours on this one though.

```
SELECT postsTable.*, votesTable.vote_type, extract(day from age(now(), votesTable.timestamp)) age 
FROM posts AS postsTable 
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT * FROM votes) 
AS votesTable ON (postsTable.id = votesTable.post_id)
ORDER BY vote_type DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 10;
```

Returns:

```
 ---- ---------------------- ----------- -----
| id | other_colums_between | vote_type | age |
 ---- ---------------------- ----------- -----
| 8  | ...                  | 1         | 3   |
```

As you can tell I am a beginner in SQL. I also ask for some advice as to how I can simplify the queries above. Thank you for your help.

Comment: So, if I understood it right, you should just move this where `WHERE (extract(day from age(now(), timestamp)) < 1)` to the outside query.

Comment: To clarify, neutral (0) does not qualify as a vote?

Comment: Yes 0 does not qualify as a vote. @toonice

Comment: Then I shall adjust my answer accordingly.  Out of curiosity, why would a neutral vote appear in the Votes table then?

Comment: For the purposes of what you are trying to achieve, are you interested in counting up-votes and down-votes, just up-votes, or those Posts with the greatest sum value?

Comment: @toonice the neutral vote isn't necessarily needed for this query. To answer your second question, I'm just interested in the sum of all votes.

Answer (score 0):

I can just think of this, but I haven't tested.

```
SELECT postsTable.*, votesTable.votes FROM posts AS postsTable RIGHT JOIN ( SELECT sum(vote_type) votes, post_id FROM votes WHERE votes.post_id IN (select unique v.post_id  from votes as v where( extract(day from age(now(), timestamp)) < 1) ) GROUP BY post_id) AS votesTable ON (postsTable.id = votesTable.post_id) ORDER BY votes DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Sorry I am getting a syntax error `at or near "v"`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try...

```
SELECT posts.*,
       votesTotal AS Votes
FROM posts
JOIN
(
    SELECT post_id AS post_id,
           SUM( vote_type ) AS votesTotal
    FROM votes
    WHERE timestamp > NOW() + INTERVAL '-1 day'
    GROUP BY post_id
    ORDER BY votesTotal DESC
    LIMIT 10
) postCounter ON postCounter.post_id = posts.id;
```

Firstly, a `RIGHT JOIN` would match *all* of the records from `Posts` with their corresponding records from the subquery whereas by using a `JOIN` (aka an `INNER JOIN`) above I have limited the results to the top 10 posts with votes from the past 24 hours.  If there are less than 10 posts with votes in the last 24 hours then it shall return only that number.  If you still require 10 records and are happy with the remaining records being a semirandom selection then change the `JOIN` to a `RIGHT JOIN` and add `LIMIT 10` to the end of the outer `SELECT` statement.  If you require the extra records but with a specific sort pattern, then you will need to specify the pattern before I can code for it.

Secondly, `NOW() + INTERVAL '-1 day'` will produce the datetime 24 hours before the current datetime.  The `WHERE` statement of which it is part will limit our results to those votes from the past 24 hours.

Without `GROUP BY` the inner query would return as many rows with `post_id` and `votesTotal` as there are rows with that `post_id` meeting our `WHERE` criteria.  `GROUP BY` (in conjunction with `SUM`) has the effect of reducing that to one row for each `post_id`.

`LIMIT 10` gives us the *first* 10 records produced by the rest of the inner query.  To ensure that they are also the *top* 10 I made sure that the list was sorted using `ORDER BY`.

Further reading...

http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/dateadd

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp (the Venn diagram can be especially helpful)

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/queries-limit.html

If you have any questions or comments, then please post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: Sorry this doesn't work. It still returns the same results. Also, PG was throwing a syntax error for the `WHERE` case. I had to change it to `WHERE timestamp > now () + INTERVAL '-1 day'` (I've never used INTERVAL and I think that's how it should be done as this returns results). Thanks for taking the time to comment and post an answer though.

Comment: My apologies - I got distracted and forgot to change my code from my default MySQL to PostgreSQL.  Your change was the correct PostgreSQL equivalent of MySQL's `'DATE_ADD()`.  I have corrected my answer. 
 Does the code work now?

Comment: No worries. No it does not. The returned results are still the same.

Comment: I shall continue looking into this.  In the meantime I recommend against using `timestamp` as the name of a field as it is also a semireserved word used for casting / conversion purposes, as per https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html.  Instead, try sdomething like `votesTimedate` or `votes_timestamp`.

Comment: Also, if you have a script for creating and populating sample tables, then please update your question to include it.  It is considered ideal by many that a question include these when it is posed, though most people aren't too fussed by its absence at that stage since it is often not necessary.

Comment: I have done so few `ORDER BY`'s recently that I actually forgot to put `DESC` at the end of that line to sort the values from largest to smallest.  My bad.  Please advise me if this solves your problem.  I shall continue testing the code in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to put the WHERE clause on your outer table, not your inner table, since you want to filter the **posts** by date, not the **votes**.

```
SELECT postsTable.*, votesTable.votes
FROM posts AS postsTable
RIGHT JOIN (
  SELECT sum(vote_type) votes, post_id 
  FROM votes 
  GROUP BY post_id) 
  AS votesTable 
  ON (postsTable.id = votesTable.post_id)
WHERE (extract(day from age(now(), timestamp)) < 1) 
ORDER BY votes DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 10;
```

(assuming your `posts` table also has a column called `timestamp`